# ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am trying to run this query but it throws an error

ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated

Below is the query which I am using in my code.

```
"select created_at from user where username = '" + id + "' group by DATE(created_at)"
```

Comment: Check your sql mode: `SELECT  @@sql_mode;`

Comment: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: In `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode it's not possible.

Comment: @1000111, what should be the solution any change required?

Comment: should I remove ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Then I will be left with

STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DI‌​VISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: Try this: `SELECT
 DATE(created_at)
FROM
 user 
WHERE username = '" + id + "'
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the mode. You can try changing it and checking. Restart MYSQL.

But, below should work fine.

```
SELECT DATE(created_at) 
FROM user 
WHERE username = '" + id + "' 
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
```

Comment: will these remove other modes?